# jQuery add custom event listener

Tags: jquery

How to add a custom event listener to jQuery?
for example: I have an animated element, how to add an event listener that apply some actions once its coordinates equals a specific value?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't do exactly what you want.

However, you can get the same effect. The trick is, you need to put the "trigger" on the thing that will be changing.

So for instance, in your example, you want to have an animation event once the object's coordinates are in a certain value. To do this, you need to check the coordinates every time the object moves (in whatever function you use to move the object). Then if they are equal, trigger the animation function.